# jquery toggle a tab's active state when visited from external link

Tags: jquery, tabs

I have a page with 3 tabs. At any time, 2 of the tabs are hidden. There is a subnavigation menu to handle this show/hide function. When you click a link on the subnav, that tab opens and the subnav shows that tab link as active (via different font color). Great! But...

**PROBLEM**
However, when I visit that tab from an external link (like "http://example.com#subDivTab2"), it IS going to the tab and showing it, but it ISN'T triggering that active state. The font color for that link in the subnav is not changing. It should mimic opening the tab if on the same page and showing the font color change.

**TAB SWITCH CODE**

```
$('a.subDivSwitchLink').click(function (e) {
    var $this = $(this),
    containerSelector = $this.attr('href'),
    $links = $('a.subDivSwitchLink');
    e.preventDefault();
    $('div.subDivSwitch').not(containerSelector).hide();
    $(containerSelector).show();
    //active tab state
    $links.not($this).toggleClass('subTitleActive', false);
    $this.toggleClass('subTitleActive', true);
});
```

**ACTIVE STATE TRIGGER (when on same page)**
*This is what triggers the tab opening*

```
var target = '#'+'subDivTab1';
$('a[href="'+target+'"].subDivSwitchLink').click();
```

**EXTERNAL LINK TAB OPEN CODE**
*This is what triggers the tab opening from an external link*

```
var hash = $.trim(window.location.hash);
$('a[href="'+hash+'"].subDivSwitchLink').click();
```

**ATTEMPT**
*I've tried the following, but it isn't working*

```
var hash = ($.trim(window.location.hash)+'subDivTab1');
$('a[href="'+hash+'"].subDivSwitchLink').click();
```

**FIDDLE**
*Reduced case fiddle to help*
http://jsfiddle.net/zuhloobie/m1fua9jp/

Comment: I edited my code with correction, the hash should not be '+ subDivTab1'

Comment: I have updated my answer to solve the issues you have mentioned. Please let me know how it goes.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You were on the right track when you used `window.location.hash` to detect the current tab. Just use jQuery variables like you were doing to trigger the classes:

```
var hash = $.trim(window.location.hash);
if(!hash){
    hash = $('a.subDivSwitchLink:first').attr('href');
}

var activeTab = $('a[href="'+hash+'"].subDivSwitchLink');

$('a.subDivSwitchLink').toggleClass('subTitleActive', false);
$('a.subDivSwitchLink')
    .each(function(){
        $($(this).attr('href')).hide();
    });

activeTab.toggleClass('subTitleActive', true);
$(hash).show();
```

Comment: Thank you for your response - it isn't working. Couple problems: (1) If my external link is http://example.com/subDivTab2 it opens up that tab directly and its link IS showing the active state, but it is showing subDivTab1's content instead of subDivTab2's. (2) If I go to the page (http://example.com) it no longer has tab1's link as active - none are active. (3) If I use another link to tab2 inside tab1's content (separate from subnav), it doesn't trigger tab2's active state either.

Comment: Your new code (thank you) isn't working :/ Any subnav link with the class of `subDivSwitchLink` is now hidden because of `$('a.subDivSwitchLink').hide();` in your code - so none of the subnav links are showing, as well as any secondary links in a tab's content.

Comment: @chris, if you can replicate it in a fiddle, I would better be able to help you. Good luck

Comment: Yep - I'm creating a reduced case on JSFiddle right now.

Comment: Added fiddle to question

Comment: @chris I have updated the code in my answer and tried it in this fiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/m1fua9jp/1/ Let me know how it goes

Comment: I think you have it except for one thing - on tab 2, clicking on that secondary link in orange should take you to tab 3, which it does, but it isn't reading the active state.